# What type of Shader does Three.JS apply to models imported via ColladaLoader?

Tags: three.js

I am trying to work out what type of shader is applied to materials of models imported via the Collada Loader.

The output is so much better looking than all the combinations of materials/shaders I've been trying to create!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the function you're after:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/loaders/ColladaLoader.js#L3059